# admob is working on test id but not with live id

Tags: android, admob

I have added admob banner ad code on my app, it is working fine in test env with test id but as soon as I publish it on playstore with LIVE id it stops working, I am using following code.

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-***********");
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/adUnitId"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: I hope you have enabled ` Contains Ads` tag from Play Store console.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled Contains Ads on Play Store console but I am not getting whats a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google Admob, if test ad is working the live ad will also work because they got generated from same channel. In live ad situation it can take time up to 1-4 days to start, so just wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mail, just to be sure you haven't violated any AdMob rules or whatevs. They could disable serving ads to an app or your account. Sometime they did that to mine i took 4 days to notice.

Answer (score 0):

It works don't take tension. If your Admob account is new then it may take time up to one month to start showing live Ads.

You may also verify if you have provided the right billing address in your AdMob account, if you have then you should see the given message

> Congratulation we have verified your Account.

A month back when I created a new AdMob account, the ads were not showing up so do verify your billing address as mentioned.

In your case, live Ads Are not showing, my live Ads were showing as soon as I generated a signed APK from Android Studio without the app being published on play store.